# Proving steps of the Proof that every finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

I'm reading through this proof that every finite abelian group is isomorphic to a direct product of cyclic groups, and I need to prove three steps in it but I'm unsure how to. The proof is as follows:

Let $A$ be a finite abelian p-group, where $|A| = p^\alpha$.

We prove this by induction of $|A|$.

Base step: $\alpha = 1$, so $|A| = p \implies A$ is cyclic.

Define homomorphism $\phi:A \rightarrow A, \phi(x) = x^p.$

$Kernel(\phi) = K,$ image of $\phi = H$.

By Cauchy's theorem, $|K| \neq 1$ and $H \neq A,$ then $|H| < |A| \implies H \cong \langle h_1\rangle \times ....\times\langle h_r\rangle$.

For each $h_i, \exists g_i \in A$ such that $g_i^p = h_i$.

$A_0 = \langle g_1, ....,g_r\rangle$

Now here's the part I'm stuck on. I need to prove the three following points:

1. $A_0 \cong \langle g_1\rangle \times ....\times\langle g_r\rangle$
2. $A_0/H \cong \langle g_1H\rangle \times ....\times\langle g_rH\rangle$
3. $H\cap K \cong \langle {h_1^p}^{\alpha_1 - 1}\rangle\times....\times\langle {h_1^p}^{\alpha_r - 1}\rangle$

I think that (2) follows from (1), but I'm not sure about (3).

I think that one way to prove (1) is to assume toward contradiction that $$\langle \{g_1, ...., g_r\} - \{g_n\}\rangle\cap\langle g_n\rangle \neq 1,$$ then show that this would contradict our definition of $H$, but I'm unsure how to do this. Any and all help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

For (1), just take any expression

$$\sum a_i g_i = 0$$

then passing $\phi$ we get

$$\sum a_i h_i = 0 \; ,$$

contradiction, since the $h_i$ independent.

For (2), you're right that independence carries over:

> If
>  $$\sum a_i g_i = h \implies \sum a_i g_i - \sum (b_i p) g_i  = 0$$
>  hence $(a_i - b_i p) g_i = 0$ for each $i$, hence $a_i g_i = (b_i p) g_i = b_i h_i$, so $a_i g_i \in H$ for each $i$.

Now you can apply the first isomorphism theorem to conclude.

Finally, for (3),

> Let $p^{\alpha_i}$ be the order of $h_i$.
>  $$p\left( \sum a_i h_i \right) = 0 \implies p^{\alpha_i} \mid p a_i$$
>  hence $a_i = rp^{\alpha_i - 1}$.

Comment: I don't follow: groups have one operation, only.

Comment: @tron Well, the groups in question are abelian.